# Regex fuzzy word match

Tags: python, regex, parsing, information-extraction

Tough regex question: I want to use regexes to extract information from news sentences about crackdowns.  Here are some examples:

```
doc1 = "5 young students arrested"
doc2 = "10 rebels were reported killed"
```

I want to match sentences based on lists of entities and outcomes:

```
entities = ['students','rebels']
outcomes = ['arrested','killed']
```

How can I use a regex to extract the number of participants from 0-99999, any of the entities, any of the outcomes, all while ignoring random text (such as 'young' or 'were reported')?  This is what I have:

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,5} \D{1,50}'+ '|'.join(entities) + '\D{1,50}' + '|'.join(outcomes),doc1)
```

i.e., a number, some optional random text, an entity, some more optional random text, and an outcome. 
Something is going wrong, I think because of the OR statements.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a common task in Natural Language Processing. You should google that and see how it's done properly in Python. I've used Stanford Parser (Java) in the past which saved me a lot of time: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Comment: This is not something you should do purely with regex

Comment: As an alternative solution you could look into nltk. It provides functions to tag words (annoate words with grammatical information), then you could look for combinations of entities, passive voice and numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers!  @ReutSharabani, is the Stanford Parser better even with tailored applications, when you know the specific entities and actions of interest?  I thought it might not be, but I could (definitely) be wrong.

Comment: @user1060859 , While you could use regex for a quick hack if it's just something you're poking at - NLP tools **are the right tools** here. You need to do stemming, sentence extraction, tokenization, ignore grammatical errors and more. All these were already addressed by professionals, why would you want to solve it again? *Please* use `nltk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should match your two examples:

```
pattern = r'\d+\s+.*?(' + '|'.join(entities) + r').*?(' + '|'.join(outcomes) + ')'
```

What you were missing were parentheses around the ORs.

However, using only regex likely won't give you good results.  Consider using Natural Language Processing libraries like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) that parses sentences.

Answer (score 0):

As @ReutSharabani already answered, this is not a proper way to do nlp, but this answers the literal question.

The regex should read:

```
import re;
entities = ['students','rebels'];
outcomes = ['arrested','killed'];
p = re.compile(r'(\d{1,5})\D{1,50}('+'|'.join(entities)+')\D{1,50}('+'|'.join(outcomes)+')');
m = p.match(doc1);
number = m.group(1);
entity = m.group(2);
outcome = m.group(3);
```

You forgot to group `()` your OR-operations. Instead what you generated was `a|b|\W|c|d|\W` (short version).

Comment: Just a note for `\D{1,50}`: Those words are optional (beginning of the `doc2` for example)

Comment: Well `\D` can match a space as well. I guess the OP only wanted to limit the reach. If the span between `5` and `students` is longer than 50 chars, it is very unlikely that the two are related.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to try out the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module!
It has built in fuzzy match capabilities.  The other answers seem much more robust and sleek, but this could be done simply with fuzzy matching as well!

```
pattern = r'\d{1,5}(%(entities)s)(%(outcomes)s){i}' %{'entities' : '|'.join(entities), 'outcomes' : '|'.join(outcomes)}
regex.match(pattern, news_sentence)
```

What's happening here is that the {i} indicates you want a match with any number of inserts.  The problem here is that it could insert characters into one of the entities or outcomes and still yield a match.  If you want to accept slight alterations on spelling to any of your outcomes or entities, then you could also use {e<=1} or something.  Read more in the provided link about approximate matching!

Comment: I misread the original question!  This is not a good answer, but still a useful tool to have nonetheless.  I think what you want to do instead is just to collect all the instances of <number><entities><outcomes> allowing anything that isn't a period in between i.e. [^.]*, and then using re.sub to take out everything that is not an entity, number or outcome.